# Advanced regex with grouping and maybe lookarounds

Tags: java, regex

Okay so i want to separate certain assignments into groups out of a string with the help of a regular expression in java.

My String looks like this:

```
LogEventDefinition(
logEvent = LogEvent.MESSAGE700,
process = process.Data,
processStep = "action")
```

my final solution should group it like this:

```
group 1      group 2
logEvent     LogEvent.MESSAGE700
process      process.Data
processStep  action
```

My idea is this:

`(?=@LogEventDefinition\()(\w+)\s=(\s\w+)|(?:\s\w+\.(\w+))\\)`

I do a lookahead and then check the following content of the String LogEventDefinition from the first bracket on. Essentially it is totally wrong, tried a few other attempts but nothing works, would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: I think you need more than a regex for accomplishing this. May I know why you wanna use regex? Maybe a simple code can generate this output without regex.

Comment: Well essentially because the software designed demands it, at least a regular expression for just extracting these exact patterns would at the end cause much less confusion within the code for extensions.

Comment: Always remember if regex is used on a very large string or a file it may cause efficiency loss.

Comment: " the software designed demands it"  - you might want to elaborate on this as it will definitely help to better understand the requirements. As an example, Java regex doesn't support capturing multiple matches into a group, i.e. you'd have to apply the regex multiple times. Whether that's a viable approach or not depends on what the software does - and if you're free to use some code a non-regex expression might be even easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could even handle this without setting up a formal regex:

```
String input  = "LogEventDefinition(";
       input += "logEvent = LogEvent.MESSAGE700,";
       input += "process = process.Data,";
       input += "processStep = \"action\")";

input = input.replaceAll("\\w+\\((.*)\\)", "$1");  // remove function wrapper
String[] parts = input.split(",\\s*");             // split terms by comma
List<String> group1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> group2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (String part : parts) {
    group1.add(part.split("\\s*=\\s*")[0]);        // assign group1 term
    group2.add(part.split("\\s*=\\s*")[1]);        // assign group2 term
}

System.out.println("group1, group2");
for (int i=0; i < group1.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(group1.get(i) + ", " + group2.get(i));
}
```

As a side note, I can't figure out if you want to remove quotes around terms, or whether any of your original data has quotes in the first place.  If you want to remove quotes, I can make a tiny fix to the above code to handle this requirement.

**Output:**

```
group1, group2
logEvent, LogEvent.MESSAGE700
process, process.Data
processStep, "action"
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Indeed i did realize its much easier by just slpitting the string by some symbols and then recollecting the parts in a list or anything, but the problem is that due to coding constraints i will have to find a regular expression for this. If only grouping of multiple matches is not possible in java, then it is okay for me not finding a regular expression. where did you find out that grouping multiple matches in java is not possible?

Comment: Thanks for the Rextester, ill have a look at that one!

Comment: Okay so i found an expression to easily extract just the content within the brackets:

`(?<=@LogEventDefinition\()([^\)]*)`

Is there any way now to continue working with the results of this regex with another regex, e.g. a pipe in unix?

expression->regex1->result of regex 1 on on expression->regex2->result of regex2 on result of regex1

Comment: Yes you could use a formal Java pattern matcher.  But I actually prefer using `String#split` because it is more terse and easier to read.